# How to display PUWG1992 map in Java

Tags: java, gis

Is it possible to display PUWG 1992 map in java?

If there is no Java library maybe there is another way, for example using C code?

Comment: What is "PUWG 1992" or "PUWG 1992 map"?

Comment: It's coordinate system 1992, in polish wiki it is: https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uk%C5%82ad_wsp%C3%B3%C5%82rz%C4%99dnych_1992